# How to select the element in a webpage using Ui path - Not by mouse click

Tags: rpa, uipath

I am new to UIpath, I have past experiences in web scraping using VBA with selenium web driver.

So I want click a button with the below element.

```
> <a href="#" id="toggle2" class="btn btn-primary" style="float:right;">
```

Usually I can do this in VBA with selenium web driver with this code

```
> driver.findelementbyid("toggle2").click
```

So in Ui-path I am able to do this using click activity, but the problem is the button comes at the top right corner which is being overlapped by another popup given by an browser extension.

So what I want is to click the button but not via mouse.
Also, I tried to use select activity but that only works in dropdown.

The process involves lot of area where the button actual overlapped by other pop ups.
I know that we can close the pop up provided by the browser extension and then continue, however the popup does not shows every time when I run the script.
So I am trying to do this just like selecting the element without mouse activity.

[image: This is the Browser extension pop-up]

[image: This is actual button I need to click]

Comment: Maybe you can share an image and the website and also the addon that is generating the popup. Overall using the Click activity should be ignoring the addon popup. But sounds interesting. Please share more info about that.

Comment: The website has company info so cannot share that but I can share the screenshot, updated the same in the question.

Comment: @kwoxer - I have updated the question with the screenshots. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Use the Click button to close the popup window, then again use the click activity to click the element you want to.

Answer (score 0):

have you checked the  properties like simulate click in click activity. It will works in background it. no need of ui visibility for it let's have a try